# pakage darryldecode/cart laravel Cart::add() function not working

Tags: php, laravel, axios

i am adding cart with item using Cart::add function of darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart library and item added successfully in the cart by an (axios post request call) but when i am posting second (axios post request call) to get the information of cart in next request cart is empty

getting added items code (First axios call)

```
Cart::add([
                        'id' => $item->id,
                        'name' => $item->name,
                        'price' => !$license->coefficient ? $item->price : round($license->coefficient * $item->price, 2),
                        'quantity' => 1,
                        'attributes' => [
                            'license_id' => $request->get('licenseId')
                        ]
                    ]);
```

getting added items code (second axios call) which is return empty

```
foreach (Cart::getContent() as $item) {
            if (($currentItem = Item::with('creator.country_info')->find($item->id))) {
                $itemVat = round($vat * $item->price / 100, 2);
                $subtotal += $item->price - $itemVat;
                $vatTotal += $itemVat;
                $items[] = [
                    'id' => $item->id,
                    'name' => $item->name,
                    'price' => $item->price,
                    'quantity' => $item->quantity,
                    'attributes' => $currentItem
                ];
            }
        }
```

Comment: did you manage to fix it??

Comment: I'm performing ajax on adding items to cart sometimes it work perfectly but sometimes Cart::add return true still the item is not added to cart. Does anyone have any idea why?